# JavaScript not returning the right value (position of an element)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, position

I am trying to get the position of an element (password input) on the webpage http://login.secureserver.net/index.php?app=wbe . I type this code in the javascript console in Chrome

```
function fp(obj){
    var x=0,y= 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            x+= obj.offsetLeft;
            y+= obj.offsetTop;
           } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
};
fp(document.getElementById('password'));
console.log("x="+x+"; y="+y)
```

and it returns x=809; y=380.

When measuring the screenshot with photoshop it appears to have x=816; y=388.

So what's the problem and why it is not returning the real distance?

Comment: what is your object? maybe it is an image which has width and height that you are not consider it!

Comment: it's a password input

Comment: My guess would be that it has something to do with the css style of one of the involved elements. You could try to use `element.getBoundingClientRect();` as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element Maybe this will lead to a different result?

Comment: you `var` your `x` and `y` in your _function_ but don't return them

Comment: @basilikum it is working now. Please provide an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: if you are getting x=809; y=380 and expect x=816; y=388 i would think there are some borders involve..

Comment: @gezzuzz element.getBoundingClientRect(); is working just perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included the tag [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your question, so I assume you are already using it.

I'd recommend using the function [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) for this, which should return the X and the Y coordinates of your [password input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.password.html):

```
var p = $('#password').position();
console.log("x=" + p.left + "; y=" + p.top);
```

If you are not using jQuery, [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t21) is fine, but it doesn't have the cross-browser fixes jQuery provides.

Comment: I am not using jQuery, I need it with javascript.

Comment: @Enve Then your best choice is to use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.